# pass-by-Value,Pass-by-reference and changing value of object in Generic list VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Hi I am just trying to do something with Byref and ByVal in vb I am passing my object through a method and trying to cange the value of object but I am not clear on it please anybody can help me to understand this two concept clearly.Below is the method where I am trying to change the value of arr List but it is giving exception that the Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.Please help to understand this logic of Byval and Byref.

```
   Public Function arrayReturn() As List(Of Object)
        Dim arr As List(Of Object)
        arr = New List(Of Object)
        For index As Integer = 1 To 5
            arr.Add(index)
            Debug.Write(index.ToString & " ")
        Next
        For Each i As Object In arr
            arr.Add(intReturn(i))
        Next
        Return arr
    End Function
    Public Function intReturn(ByRef i As Object) As Integer
        i += i
        Return i
    End Function
    Sub Main()
        Dim obj As List(Of Object)
        obj = New List(Of Object)
        obj = arrayReturn()
        For Each obj2 As Object In obj
            Console.WriteLine(obj2)
        Next
    End Sub
```

My Problem is with this method here I am trying to retrive an event object and putting it in a list of event but I am not getting wheter I am right or not

```
Public Function GetIcalForAppointments(nxtMonth As Integer, prevMonth As Integer, strStaffAPIKey As String) As Ical.NET.Calendar
        Dim objDTOIcallApt As DTOICallAppt
        objDTOIcallApt = New DTOICallAppt
        Dim lst As List(Of DOAppointment)

        objDTOIcallApt = GetAllAppointmentsForIcal(nxtMonth, prevMonth, strStaffAPIKey)
        lst = objDTOIcallApt.Appointments
        Dim timeZoneName As String = objDTOIcallApt.UserTimezone
        Dim calendar As Ical.NET.Calendar
        calendar = New Ical.NET.Calendar()
        Dim timeZone As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName)
        calendar.AddTimeZone(New Ical.NET.VTimeZone(timeZoneName))
        Dim evt As Ical.NET.Event
        For Each appt As DOAppointment In lst
            GetIcalForAppointment(appt, objDTOIcallApt, calendar, evt)
        Next
        Return calendar

    End Function


Public Function GetIcalForAppointment(app As DOAppointment, objResponse As DTOICallAppt, calendar As Ical.NET.Calendar, ByRef evt As Ical.NET.Event) As Ical.NET.Event

        evt = calendar.Create(Of Ical.NET.Event)()
        evt.Start = getCalDateTime(app.StartDate, calendar)
        evt.End = getCalDateTime(app.EndDate, calendar)
        evt.Description = app.FullSubject
        evt.Location = app.AppointmentInOrgName
        evt.IsAllDay = False
        evt.Created = getCalDateTime(app.CreatedDatetime, calendar)
        If objResponse.UserEmail <> "" AndAlso objResponse.UserEmail.Contains("@") = True Then
            evt.Organizer = New Organizer("MAILTO:" + objResponse.UserEmail)
        End If

        Select Case app.AppointmentStatus
            Case "Cancelled"
                evt.Status = Ical.NET.EventStatus.Cancelled
                Exit Select
            Case "NoShow"
                evt.Status = Ical.NET.EventStatus.Cancelled
                Exit Select
            Case "Scheduled"
                evt.Status = Ical.NET.EventStatus.Tentative
                Exit Select
            Case Else

                evt.Status = Ical.NET.EventStatus.Confirmed
                Exit Select
        End Select

        evt.Categories.Add("Work")
        evt.Comments.Add(app.CreatedDetails)
        evt.Resources.Add(app.Resource1Name)
        evt.Resources.Add(app.Resource2Name)
        Dim strSummary As String = app.FullSubject
        If app.IsPatConsentRequired = True Then
            If app.IsPatConsentGiven = True Then
                strSummary = strSummary & Convert.ToString(" | Consent given")
            Else
                strSummary = strSummary & Convert.ToString(" | Consent Pending")
            End If
        End If

        If app.PatMedicalHistoryCasesheetID <> "" Then
            If app.IsMedicalHistoryFilled = True Then
                strSummary = strSummary & Convert.ToString(" | Medical History filled")
            Else
                strSummary = strSummary & Convert.ToString(" | Medical History pending")
            End If
        End If

        evt.Summary = strSummary
        evt.Uid = app.ID
        Dim alarm As New Ical.NET.Alarm
        alarm.Action = Ical.NET.AlarmAction.Display
        alarm.Summary = "Appointment with " + app.AppointmentWithFullName + " at " + app.AppointmentInOrgName
        alarm.Trigger = New Trigger(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-30))
        evt.Alarms.Add(alarm)
        Return evt

    End Function
```

So here you can see I am retrieving single event object and trying to push it in event list every time

Comment: In your second for-loop you are adding new elements instead of changing the existing ones. `arr(i) = intReturn(i)` should work.

Comment: and how to do with an object which getting populated in other method but for a foreach loop...@turamarth

Comment: if the only problem is the exception, @Turamarth is right. if you need more help, you need to rewrite your answer to state the specific problem or write multiple question for each problem. If you need a manual that explain what byref and byval are, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101(v=vs.84).aspx) it is

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't think that ByVal and ByRef have something to do with your problem. Read more about them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
I believe that your problem is related with the logic you are using.
Let's break down your arrayReturn function to see what is happening:

```
   Public Function arrayReturn() As List(Of Object)
    Dim arr As List(Of Object)
    arr = New List(Of Object)
```

> You are declaring and instantiate a generic list of objects, that's fine. By the way you can shorten this code in one line Dim arr as new List(Of Object).

```
    For index As Integer = 1 To 5
        arr.Add(index)
        Debug.Write(index.ToString & " ")
    Next
```

> You are adding 5 objects in the list, nothing wrong here.

```
    For Each i As Object In arr
```

> Here is the important point. This statement is actually a contract between you and VB, what are you say here is "For every one **of the 5 objects** in the list do something". That is, you are instructing VB to do something for every one of the 5 objects in the list or to be more specific, for every one object of the current total of objects in the list at this very specific point of time.

What VB does internally is to prepare the environment to iterate all the objects in the list, in this case 5.

```
        arr.Add(intReturn(i))
```

> Here is where you are breaking the contract. You are adding another object in the list so there aren't 5 objects anymore and the iteration cannot continue because everything was prepared by VB for 5 objects and not for 6.

This is the correct behavior, you cannot alter the count of objects when you are iterating a list period. But let's say, for the shake of the example, that you were able to do that. In that case your loop would never complete because you are saying to VB to perform an action for each object in the list and every time you are adding an item. If that item was to be taken into account then the "each" would became infinite and thus the loop would be endless. I hope you get the point

```
    Next
    Return arr
End Function
```

What I am understand from your code is that you want to add same amount of objects in the list with what is currently there, in this case 5. If that's true then you have to modify your function as follows:

```
Public Function arrayReturn() As List(Of Object)
    Dim arr As New List(Of Object)

    For index As Integer = 1 To 5
        arr.Add(index)
        Debug.Write(index.ToString & " ")
    Next

    Dim c as Integer = arr.Count

    For i As Integer = 0 to c - 1
        arr.Add(intReturn(arr(i)))
    Next

    Return arr
End Function
```

However that doesn't feel correct for an appointments app scope. For example if there are sub-appointments inside other appointments then you need a different storage structure like a tree and access / manipulate it recursively.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply but that code is just a dummy that  I am trying to pass some object and returning it in the list what actually I am trying to is in the next code where I am for each appt object trying to create event and at the end I will get a event list but for that i need to pass object as reference so that in a list of event first object is one event then comes next and then next